# R: Efficient iterative subsetting and filtering of large vector

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, rcpp, dtplyr

I'd like to perform the following operation more quickly.

**Logic:** I have a vector `big` of 4 elements `1, 2, 3, 4`. I also have a same-length vector of thresholds `1.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1`. I want for each element to find the index of the first **next** element to be above the corresponding threshold. In this case my expected output is

`2, 3, NA, NA`:

- the first element *after the first one (included)* which is above the threshold of 1.1 is at index 2 (value of 2).
- The first element above the second threshold of 3.1 is of value 4, and is the **third** element *after the current one at index 2* (included).

---

**Base implementation**

```r
start <- Sys.time()
bigg <- rnorm(25000)
thresh <- bigg+0.5
result <- rep(NA, length(bigg))
for(i in 1:length(bigg)) {
  result[i] <- which(bigg[(i+1):length(bigg)]>thresh[i])[1] # the first next element that is higher than thresh
  if(i%%1000==0) print(paste0(i, " ", round(i/length(bigg),3)))
}
end <- Sys.time()
end-start
head(result)
```

Basically, taking the first element of the vector x *after the current one* that satisfies a threshold condition.

I tried using `Rcpp`

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int cppnextup_(NumericVector x, double thresh, bool is_up = true) {
  int n = x.size();
  //int idx = 0;
  int res = -1;
  for(int idx = 0; idx < n; ++idx) {
    if(x[idx]>thresh && is_up == true) {
      res = idx;
//Rcout << "The value of idx : " << idx <<" "<< x[idx]<<"\n";
      break;
    }
    if(x[idx]<thresh && is_up == false) {
      res = idx;
      //Rcout << "The value of idx : " << idx <<" "<< x[idx]<<"\n";
      break;
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

**Benchmarking:**

```r
# base --------------------------------------------------------------------

base_ <- function() {
  for(i in 1:length(bigg)) {
    result[i] <- which(bigg[(i+1):length(bigg)]>thresh[i])[1] # the first next element that is higher than thresh
    if(i%%1000==0) print(paste0(i, " ", round(i/length(bigg),3)))
  }
}

# cpp ----------------------------------------------------------------

result_cpp <- rep(NA, length(bigg))
cpp_ <- function() {
  for(i in 1:length(bigg)) {
    result_cpp[i] <- cppnextup_(bigg[(i+1):length(bigg)], thresh[i]) # the first next element that is higher than thresh
    if(i%%1000==0) print(paste0(i, " ", round(i/length(bigg),3)))
  }
}

#result_cpp <- ifelse(result_cpp==-1, NA, result_cpp)
#result_cpp <- result_cpp+1
#all.equal(result, result_cpp)
#[1] TRUE

# benchmark ---------------------------------------------------------------

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(base_(),
                               cpp_(), times=3)
Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 base_() 2023.510 2030.3154 2078.7867 2037.1211 2106.4252 2175.7293     3
  cpp_()  661.277  665.3456  718.8851  669.4141  747.6891  825.9641     3
```

My `Rcpp` implementation reduces base time by 65%, is there a better (vectorized) way? Looking for any backend, be it `Rcpp`, `data.table`, `dtplyr` etc.

My `dtplyr` attempt yields all `NA`'s:

```
library(dtplyr)
nx <- length(bigg)
df <- tibble(bigg, thresh)
bigg %>% lazy_dt() %>% mutate(res = which(bigg[row_number():nx]>thresh)[1])
Warning message:
In seq_len(.N):..nx :
  numerical expression has 25000 elements: only the first used
```

Cheers

Btw, my real vector has 8,406,600 elements.

---

EDIT: vectorized `Rcpp`

I also have another, faster `Rcpp` function which relies on the first one:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector cppnextup(NumericVector x, double threshup, bool is_up = true) {
  int n = x.size();
  NumericVector up(n);
  if(is_up == true) {
    up = x + threshup;
  } else {
    up = x - threshup;
  }
//  Rcout << "The value of up : " << up[0] <<" "<< up[1] <<"\n";
  NumericVector result(n);
  int idx = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    double thisup = up[idx];
    NumericVector thisvect = x[Rcpp::Range((idx), (n-1))];
    
//Rcout <<idx<< " " << "thisvect : " << thisvect[0] <<" thisup: "<< thisup <<" buy " << buy << "\n";
    
    int resi = cppnextup_(thisvect, thisup, is_up = is_up);
    if(resi != 0) {
      result[idx] = resi+1;
    } else {
      result[idx] = resi;
    }
    
    //Rcout << "RESI: " << resi <<" "<< up[1] <<"\n";
    idx = idx + 1;
  }
  return result;
}
```

As you can see it is faster than the previous two:

```
# cpp_vectorized ----------------------------------------------------------

cpp_vect <- function(bigg) {
  res_cppvect <- cppnextup(bigg, 0.5)
}

    # benchmark ---------------------------------------------------------------
    
    microbenchmark::microbenchmark(base_(),
                                   cpp_(), 
                                   cpp_vect(),
                                   times=3)
           expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
        base_() 2014.7211 2016.8679 2068.9869 2019.0146 2096.1198 2173.2250     3
         cpp_()  663.0874  666.1540  718.5863  669.2207  746.3357  823.4507     3
     cpp_vect()  214.1745  221.2103  223.9532  228.2460  228.8426  229.4392     3
```

BUT when I pass a larger vector in argument, it freezes and never returns a result.

```
res <- cpp_vect(bigg=rnorm(1000000)) # freezes
```

Any help welcome.

Comment: Why don't you directly include the `for(i in 1:length(bigg))` loop into the `Rcpp` code?

Comment: not in `cpp_` function you use for benchmark?

Comment: @Waldi: I have, and have updated the question.

Comment: FYI, `mutate(res = which(bigg[row_number():nx]>thresh)[1])` is (a) bad practice, you should (almost) never reference `bigg` in a pipe based on `bigg` (lazy or otherwise); and (b) certainly not doing what you want, since `row_number():nx` is effectively `1:nx` with  warning (see `(1:3):5`). You would need a rolling or similar to do what you want.

Comment: Clumsy, I know. I checked `data.table::frollapply()` but *Due to the logic of adaptive rolling functions, following restrictions apply: align only "right".* This could potentially be hacked by `rev`ersing the data, but I don't know how to define `F` with two arguments .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `data.table` non-equi join with `mult = "first"` works well. It won't be as fast as an optimized `Rcpp` function, though.

```
library(data.table)

bigg <- rnorm(25000)
thresh <- bigg+0.5
f1 <- function(bigg, thresh) {
  result <- rep(NA, length(bigg))
  for(i in 1:length(bigg)) {
    result[i] <- which(bigg[(i+1):length(bigg)]>thresh[i])[1] # the first next element that is higher than thresh
  }
  result
}

f2 <- function(bigg, thresh) {
  data.table(
    val = bigg,
    r = seq_along(bigg)
  )[
    data.table(
      val = thresh,
      r = seq_along(thresh)
    ),
    on = .(val > val, r > r),
    .(result = x.r - i.r),
    mult = "first"
  ]$result
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1 = f1(bigg, thresh),
                               f2 = f2(bigg, thresh),
                               times = 10,
                               check = "identical")
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
#>    f1 2167.139 2199.801 2217.6945 2222.4937 2233.254 2250.1693    10
#>    f2  605.999  610.576  612.0431  611.1439  614.195  618.6248    10

bigg <- rnorm(1e6)
thresh <- bigg+0.5
system.time(f2(bigg, thresh))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  375.71    0.15  375.81
```

Comment: Totally agree that this does _not_ necessarily call for `Rcpp` as `data.table` is very optimized for this type of query .. if one knows how to form it.  So thanks for the answer!

Comment: @DirkEddelBuettel, brute force `cpp` seems able to make it without much optimization (probably because of the normal distribution of test data), see my answer.

Comment: This allows to solve a range of other problems ridiculously faster, with clear syntax. Much appreciated @jblood94.

Comment: New related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73403038/r-data-table-rolling-max/73403864?noredirect=1#comment129629689_73403864

Answer (score 4):

Although this `Rcpp` code isn't optimized, it performs quite well on a 1e7 vector (less than 1 second, probably due to the normal distribution of test data):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector cppnextup_(NumericVector x, NumericVector thresh, bool is_up = true) {
  int n = x.size();
  IntegerVector res(n);
  std::fill(res.begin(), res.end(), NA_INTEGER);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++){
      if(x[j]>thresh[i] && is_up == true) {
        res[i] = j-i;
        //Rcout << "The value of idx : " << idx <<" "<< x[idx]<<"\n";
        break;
      }
      if(x[j]<thresh[i] && is_up == false) {
        res[i] = j-i;
        //Rcout << "The value of idx : " << idx <<" "<< x[idx]<<"\n";
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Speed comparison on a 1e5 vector (a longer vector would take too much time for comparison):

```
bigg <- rnorm(1e5)
thresh <- bigg+0.5
f1 <- function(bigg, thresh) {
  result <- rep(NA, length(bigg))
  for(i in 1:length(bigg)) {
    result[i] <- which(bigg[(i+1):length(bigg)]>thresh[i])[1] # the first next element that is higher than thresh
  }
  result
}

f_cpp <- function(bigg, thresh){
  cppnextup_(bigg, thresh)
  
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1 = f1(bigg, thresh),
                               f_cpp = f_cpp(bigg, thresh),
                               times = 1,
                               check="identical")

Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
    f1 59614.42 59614.42 59614.42 59614.42 59614.42 59614.42     1
 f_cpp     5.56     5.56     5.56     5.56     5.56     5.56     1
```

In a worst case scenario where the threshold is reached in the last values of the vector, the `data.table` approach shows its effectiveness :

```
bigg <- rep(0,1e5)
thresh <- bigg+0.5

bigg[(1e5-2):1e5] <- 1

microbenchmark::microbenchmark( f1 = f1(bigg, thresh),
                                f2 = f2(bigg, thresh),
                                f_cpp = f_cpp(bigg, thresh),
                                times = 1)
Unit: milliseconds
  expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
    f1 48546.2250 48546.2250 48546.2250 48546.2250 48546.2250 48546.2250     1
    f2    40.0642    40.0642    40.0642    40.0642    40.0642    40.0642     1
 f_cpp  4521.9461  4521.9461  4521.9461  4521.9461  4521.9461  4521.9461     1
```

Comment: And just to ask the obvious: you are getting the answers in both methods?  The question / suggested algorithm made me think this would be quadratice in $N$, and the `Rcpp` answer here seems too quick especially given that the `data,table` code we are thinking of is also compiled.  But hey, maybe my intuition was off. It happens....

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, `check="identical"` makes sure the results are the same. I also find it extremely quick probably because of the gaussian distribution of test data, making inner loop end after a few iterations. I'm going to test a worst case scenario.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, in worst case scenario, `data.table` optimization indeed shows its effectiveness. Performance depends strongly on nature of input data.

Comment: New related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73403038/r-data-table-rolling-max/73403864?noredirect=1#comment129629689_73403864